# WinForms sometimes appear twice and sometimes once

Tags: c#, winforms

I am confuse at this one, the windows form called **"Contact"** sometimes called twice after the **"Welcome Screen"** and sometimes it **("Contact")** is called once only. I am pretty sure that I called the form once only.

Here is the code that I am using:

***The form below "WelcomeScreen" is the first one called when run the program:***

```
public partial class WelcomeScreen : Form
    {
        int timeLeft = 5;

        Timer _timer = new Timer();

        BackgroundWorker _backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

        public WelcomeScreen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

            _backgroundWorker.DoWork += BackgroundWorker_DoWork;

            _backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += BackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged;

            _timer.Interval = 1000;

            _timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        }

        void WelcomeScreen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timeLeft--;

            if (timeLeft <= 0)
            {
                _timer.Stop();

                this.Hide();

                Contact _contact = new Contact();

                _contact.ShowDialog();

                this.Close();
            }
        }

        void BackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;

            if (e.ProgressPercentage <= 300)
            {
                _timer.Start();

                this.label3.Text = "Completed ( " + timeLeft + " ) ";
                this.label4.Text = string.Empty;
            }

        }

        void BackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 300; i++)
            {
                _backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(i);

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
            }
        }
```

***The form below "Contact" is called after the "WelcomeScreen":***

```
public partial class Contact : Form
    {
        const int CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON = 0x200;

        public Contact()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void Contact_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SystemManager.SoundEffect();
        }

        void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();

            Loading _loading = new Loading();

            _loading.ShowDialog();

            this.Close();
        }

        protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                CreateParams myCp = base.CreateParams;
                myCp.ClassStyle = myCp.ClassStyle | CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON;
                return myCp;
            }
        }
```

I appreciate your answer!

Thank you

Comment: Use break point in your code and check how many times is called. If it is twice check the Callstack and see why !

Comment: you can also check form is already open or not, If its already open don'call it. Use `WindowState`

Comment: I suppose `WindowState` is for Maximized, Minimized, and Normal only right sir @VijaySinghRana.

Comment: Thank you, will remember that to often use the break point and check the Call Stack sir @mybirthname

Comment: But why were you so lazy to debug it? Or at least Debug.WriteLining..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `Timer` is causing the issue, by firing multiple times...

You have this condition inside your timer code:

```
if (timeLeft <= 0)
```

And the line before is `timeLeft--`. After `timeLeft` becomes 0, it will continue getting smaller (-1, -2, etc) and the form will be shown each time.

A quick fix is to either change the condition to `timeLeft == 0` or change the type of `timeLeft` to a `uint`. Of course, these are both hacks. The correct fix would be to fix your code to stop the timer from firing when required.